# Background animation with depth in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, background, sprite-kit

I'm building my first game using Swift and SpriteKit and want to add a background. The game takes place in space so I wanted to have stars in the background moving at varying speeds. Currently, I'm going for a 3D look by making the larger stars move across screen faster than the smaller ones. Is there an efficient way to do this rather than making a SKNode subclass like this and adding it as a child at the start of `DidMoveToView`? It seems like this method is pretty intensive but I thought I'd try it before recycling the same image over and over.

```
class BackGroundAnimation:SKNode{

let theView:SKView
init(aView:SKView){

    theView = aView

    super.init()

    animate()
}


func animate(){


    for _ in 1...200{

        let randomSize = random(1, max: 3)
        var randomPosx = random(1,max: 1000)
        randomPosx = randomPosx/1000.0
        var randomPosy = random(1,max: 1000)
        randomPosy = randomPosy/1000.0

        let star:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture:starTexture)
        star.setScale(randomSize/60.0)



        star.position = CGPoint(x:(theView.scene?.size.width)! * randomPosx,y:(theView.scene?.size.width)! * randomPosy)//    (self.scene.size.width)*randomPosx, y:(self.scene.size.height) * randomPosy)

        //star.position = CGPoint(x: 200,y: 200)

        star.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: star.size.width/2 )
        star.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        star.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
        star.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0

        star.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        star.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx:1 * randomSize, dy:0)
        star.name = "star"

        //addChild(star)
        self.addChild(star)
        self.moveToParent(self.scene!)


    }


}




required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Any help would be great.

Comment: I believe that the method you're currently using is the proper way to implement this type of background. However if you notice extreme lag and/or slow running (due to the background) on real devices (not simulator), I'd try to scrap parts of it and bring it down to parts of the background you really need

Comment: You could use particles and just have 3 particle layers rendering at different speeds and that's it. Screenshot of what I mean: https://twitter.com/JozemiteApps/status/678734299521155072.

Comment: Look into SKEmitterNode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you can create a beautiful parallax background using particles.

Add this function anywhere in your class.

```
//Creates a new star field
func starfieldEmitterNode(speed speed: CGFloat, lifetime: CGFloat, scale: CGFloat, birthRate: CGFloat, color: SKColor) -> SKEmitterNode {
    let star = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
    star.fontSize = 80.0
    star.text = "✦"
    let textureView = SKView()
    let texture = textureView.textureFromNode(star)
    texture!.filteringMode = .Nearest

    let emitterNode = SKEmitterNode()
    emitterNode.particleTexture = texture
    emitterNode.particleBirthRate = birthRate
    emitterNode.particleColor = color
    emitterNode.particleLifetime = lifetime
    emitterNode.particleSpeed = speed
    emitterNode.particleScale = scale
    emitterNode.particleColorBlendFactor = 1
    emitterNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMaxY(frame))
    emitterNode.particlePositionRange = CGVector(dx: CGRectGetMaxX(frame), dy: 0)
    emitterNode.particleSpeedRange = 16.0

    //Rotates the stars
    emitterNode.particleAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI_4), duration: 1),
        SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_4), duration: 1)]))

    //Causes the stars to twinkle
    let twinkles = 20
    let colorSequence = SKKeyframeSequence(capacity: twinkles*2)
    let twinkleTime = 1.0 / CGFloat(twinkles)
    for i in 0..<twinkles {
        colorSequence.addKeyframeValue(SKColor.whiteColor(),time: CGFloat(i) * 2 * twinkleTime / 2)
        colorSequence.addKeyframeValue(SKColor.yellowColor(), time: (CGFloat(i) * 2 + 1) * twinkleTime / 2)
    }
    emitterNode.particleColorSequence = colorSequence

    emitterNode.advanceSimulationTime(NSTimeInterval(lifetime))
    return emitterNode
}
```

And then add this function too. This is the function that will create the layers of stars. Just call this function, such as in the didMoveToView.

```
func createStarLayers() {
    //A layer of a star field
    let starfieldNode = SKNode()
    starfieldNode.name = "starfieldNode"
    starfieldNode.addChild(starfieldEmitterNode(speed: -48, lifetime: size.height / 23, scale: 0.2, birthRate: 1, color: SKColor.lightGrayColor()))
    addChild(starfieldNode)

    //A second layer of stars
    var emitterNode = starfieldEmitterNode(speed: -32, lifetime: size.height / 10, scale: 0.14, birthRate: 2, color: SKColor.grayColor())
    emitterNode.zPosition = -10
    starfieldNode.addChild(emitterNode)

    //A third layer
    emitterNode = starfieldEmitterNode(speed: -20, lifetime: size.height / 5, scale: 0.1, birthRate: 5, color: SKColor.darkGrayColor())
    starfieldNode.addChild(emitterNode)
}
```

And this is how it looks like.

[image]

Comment: @Nik do you not know what a particle emitter is?  You end up with thousands of independent moving sprites.  Use this approach only if you do not plan on being GPU and CPU intensive

Comment: @Knight0fDragon So it's not a good approach? Sorry, I'm not super familiar with it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I currently have something similar to your current answer

Comment: @Nik if you have the cycles to spare it is a nice approach

Comment: A particle emitter is specifically optimised for having thousand of moving sprites (that are all actually a single sprite with different modifiers). Do not hesitate to use this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Updated @JozemiteApps solution for **Swift 4** / **iOS 11**

Add this function anywhere in your class.

```
//Creates a new star field
func starfieldEmitterNode(speed speed: CGFloat, lifetime: CGFloat, scale: CGFloat, birthRate: CGFloat, color: SKColor) -> SKEmitterNode {
    let star = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
    star.fontSize = 80.0
    star.text = "✦"
    let textureView = SKView()
    let texture = textureView.texture(from: star)
    texture!.filteringMode = .nearest

    let emitterNode = SKEmitterNode()
    emitterNode.particleTexture = texture
    emitterNode.particleBirthRate = birthRate
    emitterNode.particleColor = color
    emitterNode.particleLifetime = lifetime
    emitterNode.particleSpeed = speed
    emitterNode.particleScale = scale
    emitterNode.particleColorBlendFactor = 1
    emitterNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    emitterNode.particlePositionRange = CGVector(dx: frame.maxX, dy: 0)
    emitterNode.particleSpeedRange = 16.0

    //Rotates the stars
    emitterNode.particleAction = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi/4), duration: 1),
        SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/4), duration: 1)]))

    //Causes the stars to twinkle
    let twinkles = 20
    let colorSequence = SKKeyframeSequence(capacity: twinkles*2)
    let twinkleTime = 1.0 / CGFloat(twinkles)
    for i in 0..<twinkles {
        colorSequence.addKeyframeValue(SKColor.white,time: CGFloat(i) * 2 * twinkleTime / 2)
        colorSequence.addKeyframeValue(SKColor.yellow, time: (CGFloat(i) * 2 + 1) * twinkleTime / 2)
    }
    emitterNode.particleColorSequence = colorSequence

    emitterNode.advanceSimulationTime(TimeInterval(lifetime))
    return emitterNode
}
```

And then add this function too. This is the function that will create the layers of stars. Just call this function, such as in the didMoveToView.

```
func createStarLayers() {
        //A layer of a star field
        let starfieldNode = SKNode()
        starfieldNode.name = "starfieldNode"
        starfieldNode.addChild(starfieldEmitterNode(speed: -48, lifetime: size.height / 23, scale: 0.2, birthRate: 1, color: SKColor.lightGray))
        addChild(starfieldNode)

        //A second layer of stars
        var emitterNode = starfieldEmitterNode(speed: -32, lifetime: size.height / 10, scale: 0.14, birthRate: 2, color: SKColor.gray)
        emitterNode.zPosition = -10
        starfieldNode.addChild(emitterNode)

        //A third layer
        emitterNode = starfieldEmitterNode(speed: -20, lifetime: size.height / 5, scale: 0.1, birthRate: 5, color: SKColor.darkGray)
        starfieldNode.addChild(emitterNode)
    }
```

Comment: Note it appears that the particleActions do not work in iOS 10 +

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it without particles is you create layers,  and just move the individual layers

So create a background SKNode,  fill it with your background sprites

Create a foreground SKNode,  fill it with your foreground sprites

Add background as a child of foreground, give it a zPosition of at least -1

Then you move the foreground, whatever you move the foreground, you move the background in the opposite direction, usually at a smaller percentage of it (I like using half).  If your foreground moves 10 pixels left, you move the background 5 pixels right

Since all of your nodes are inside these layers,  all nodes will move when you move the layer